# Understand named functions with Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm writing a function that seems like it should work just fine. But I think I'm missing something that is core to elixir. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
defmodule ProjectEuler do
  def solve(limit) do
    multiple_of_3_or_5? = fn(n) -> (rem(n, 3) == 0 || rem(n, 5) == 0) end
    for(n <- limit, multiple_of_3_or_5?.(n), do: n) |> Enum.reduce(0, fn(x, y) -> (x + y) end)
  end

  def print do
    IO.puts solve(1000)
  end
end
```

This is the first problem of Project Euler. I don't understand why this doesn't return a valid number? Instead I get this error

```
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for 1000
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is the equivalent of

```
for n <- 1000 do
  ...
end
```

The number `1000` is not an enumerable. You will want to use a [Range](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Range.html) for this

```
for n <- 1..limit do
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

After studying Elixir a bit, I came up with this version of the first Project Euler problem.

I think it's clearer!

```
#!/usr/bin/env elixir
defmodule Problem001 do
  def solve do
    1..999
    |> Enum.filter(fn(x) -> rem(x, 3) == 0 || rem(x, 5) == 0 end)
    |> Enum.sum()
  end
end

IO.puts Problem001.solve
```

It iterates over a range (1..999), filters the numbers that are divisible by 3 or 5 and then sums them all up.